# ACF: Dynamically Populate Number Fields Value Based Select Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF load_field hook to dynamically populate the choices of a select field (map_marker). It selects from a database table created by a maps plugin and gives me the column ID and marker name. It works fine.

Code which populates select field:

```
<?php 

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=map_marker', 'acf_mapsmarker_choices');

function acf_mapsmarker_choices($field){

  $field['choices'] = array();

  global $wpdb;

  $results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'leafletmapsmarker_markers ORDER BY ID ASC');  

  if(!empty($results)) :

  foreach($results as $result) :

    $value = $result->id;
    $label = $result->markername;

    $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;

  endforeach;
  endif;
  return $field;
}

?>
```

Now I'd like to use the selected value to populate two separate number fields ('marker_lat', and 'marker_lon').

These fields values are stored in the same DB table under columns 'lon' and 'lat' so essentially I need to use another 2 load_field functions to populate these fields values based on the select field value:

```
   <?php 
    add_filter('acf/load_field/name=marker_lat', 'rar_acf_mapsmarker_latitude');
    function rar_acf_mapsmarker_latitude($field){

     $field['value'] = '';

      global $wpdb;
      $results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'leafletmapsmarker_markers ORDER BY ID ASC');  
      if(!empty($results)) :

      //get the first value on the array
      $value = $results[0]->lat;

      //update the field value
      $field['value'] = $value;
      endif;
      return $field;

    }
    ?>
```

This loads the first table entry but I’m struggling to figure out how to use the selected value from the original array to populate these number fields.

Does anybody have any experience with doing this sort of thing?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Hey @Marco, did you ever find out how to do this? I have the same problem right now. Thanks